# Bash script runs in shell, gives "not found" error in crontab

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, cron

I am using an EC2 instance, crontab, and [slack-cleaner](https://github.com/kfei/slack-cleaner) to delete all Slack messages older than 48 hours. To do this, I created delete_slack.sh (I've deleted my slack api token):

```
for CHANNEL in random general
do
slack-cleaner --token <MY TOKEN> --message --channel $CHANNEL --user "*" --before $(date -d '48 hour ago' "+%Y%m%d") --perform
done
```

Then I created a crontab line to run it every minute (once it works I'll change the timing to once a day) and had cron spit out the results to a log file:

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/delete_slack/delete_slack.sh >> /var/log/delete_slack.log 2>&1
```

To test, I ran `sh /home/ubuntu/delete_slack/delete_slack.sh >> /var/log/delete_slack.log 2>&1` in the shell and it works fine. However, when I let the crontab run I get an error in the log file:

```
/home/ubuntu/delete_slack/delete_slack.sh: 3: /home/ubuntu/delete_slack/delete_slack.sh: slack-cleaner: not found
```

Any ideas? I've been banging my head against this all afternoon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the PATH you get via cron and the PATH you get through your login are different.

Either set the PATH in your script or use the absolute path to `slack-cleaner`

The PATH tells the shell which directories to search for executables (including scripts). You can `echo $PATH` to compare your path to the one cron gives and confirm that this is the issue.

If using the absolute path works, that is simplest, but if `slack-cleaner` uses other exes itself, setting the path may be better.

If you want to go the "modify PATH" method then you want to append the correct path to existing PATH and not completely overwrite it. i.e. `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/slack-cleaner-dir`. You can always use `which slack-cleaner` to find out the correct path. NOTE: you want the directory without "slack-cleaner" appended to the end.

Comment: Sorry, I am new at this, what do you mean by "set the PATH in your script"

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir/of/slack-cleaner` (obviously you don't want slack-cleaner at the end, just the dir where it lives) - This tells the shell which directories to search for executables/scripts. By using `$PATH:...` you are appending to the existing path.

Comment: This was it. Perfect thanks. The reason was because `slack-cleaner` was installed on anaconda's environment but cron apparently uses a different python environment so it couldn't find `slack-cleaner`. Live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

ALWAYS use full path in crons and you'll save a lot of time. 
If you don't like `export PATH=...` then just use `/path/to/slack-cleaner-dir` instead.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `/home/anaconda3/slack-cleaner --token <MY TOKEN> --message --channel $CHANNEL --user "*" --before $(date -d '48 hour ago' "+%Y%m%d") --perform`?

Comment: Correct. If any other file mentioned in the commend line them make sure it has full path too. Even if $CHANNEL represents a file - add the full path to the variable content too. You'll really save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Just load your profile before running the command to be in the exact same situation as when you launch it from your shell :

```
* * * * * . ~/.profile;/home/ubuntu/delete_slack/delete_slack.sh >> /var/log/delete_slack.log 2>&1
```

As I read that you're a bit new to this, here are just some more explanations about the profile :
The profile is a file loaded automatically when you connect in shell with your user.
The file is hidden in your home directory, to see it, you can launch :

```
ls -la ~
```

If you're in `bash`, the file will be named `.bash_profile`, if you're in `shell` or `ksh`, it will be named `.profile`

Hope it helped !